# Выравнивание по сетке

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Здравствуйте! Никак не могу выровнять эти дивы по одной линии без margin, padding, как это реализовать?

Прикладываю разметку

CSS:

```
p.main {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 3.000em;
  color: #404040;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.line {
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #626060;
  height: 75px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}

p.text {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  color: #404040;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.fa-heart-o {
  border: 5px solid #242424;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-heart-o:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

.fa-toggle-on {
  border: 5px solid #292929;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-toggle-on:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up {
  border: 5px solid #292929;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-radius: 40px;
  border-width: thin;
  margin-top: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.25s;
}

.fa-thumbs-o-up:hover {
  color: #249cce;
  transition: 0.25s;
  border: 1px solid #249cce;
}

p.onblock {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.313em;
  color: #404040;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

.horizontal {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #6a6a6a;
  height: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-top: 2%;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="main">About me</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> amet, ad quo dico detraxit<br> recusabo interpretaris concludaturque</p>
            </div>
        </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-md-offset-4">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">My life</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">It's worked</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Seems good</p>
        </div>

        <div class="horizontal"></div>
      </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="main">Portfolio</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-1">
              <div class="line"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
              <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit<br> amet, ad quo dico detraxit<br> recusabo interpretaris concludaturque</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: "По одной линии" - по какой? Если надо выровнять содержимое ячеек по центру, то добавитьте к `row` класс `text-center`.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Мне нужно чтобы блок что стоит между About me и Portfolio был по центру, т.е it's worked был четко где я нарисовал красную линию

Comment: Если убрать вложенность и офсеты, он сам окажется оп центру.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky обновил скриншот

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Не вкладывайте ячейки в ячейки. Ячейки должны быть внутри ряда. Чтобы сделать вложенные ячейки, вкладывайте и ряд тоже: container > row > col > row > col
2. Чтобы отодвинуть ячейки от левого края, добавьте офсет только самой левой из них.
3. Упростите структуру ячеек и отступов. Тогда края и центры разных рядов начнут совпадать сами.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
      <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p class="onblock">My life</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p class="onblock">It's worked</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
      <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <p class="onblock">Seems good</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Первый и третий ряды можно собрать по аналогии со вторым. И всю эту конструкцию можно вложить уже в другую ячейку, которую и подвинуть, куда надо.

```css
.border-left {
  border-left: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          About me
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right border-left">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad quo dico detraxit recusabo interpretaris concludaturque
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
          <i class="fa fa-heart-o fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">My life</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
          <i class="fa fa-toggle-on fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">It's worked</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
          <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          <p class="onblock">Seems good</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          About me
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 text-right border-left">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad quo dico detraxit recusabo interpretaris concludaturque
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: К сожалению это не совсем то, ссылка на PEN: http://codepen.io/Tvarinskyy/pen/PmaqQr

Comment: Обновил ответ. Идея та же. Можно усложнить и украсить так, как требует задача.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/full/aWQvWJ/  так ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Да, можете закинуть в ответ, спасибо c:

Comment: Кемарского выбери лучшим ответом ... он мне много помогал

Comment: @МаксимЛенский Сделано c: